# Why is jslint producing an error here?

Tags: javascript

Regarding the code snippet below:

```
if (type === '#') {
    return doc.getElementById(identifier);
} else if (type === '.' && doc.getElementsByClassName) {
    return doc.getElementsByClassName(identifier);
} else if (type === '@') {
    return doc.getElementsByName(identifier);
}
```

[image]

It appears not to lik the if / else if all together?

Comment: `doc.getElementsByClassName` hasn't any point since it will return a native function (it will be always `true`).

Comment: The reason is, in each of your `if` blocks, you `return` ... so, there's no need for `else if`, only `if` (jslint is so damned stupidly and painfully "strict")

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, it doesn't even allow valid code that is recorded as an "error" to be added to an "ignore error" list. This code looks somewhat valid as long as everything is properly set up and the variables are all defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `return` in your `if` block, so any `else` and `else if` blocks following it are unnecessary since they would never be evaluated if the function returned.
Try change the `else if`s to just `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the `else if (type === '.' && doc.getElementsByClassName) {` is missing the class in `doc.getElementsByClassName`

You should add the class name, i.e.:

```
doc.getElementsByClassName('className');
```